# scons cross-compilation for ARM64 target on x86-64 host

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, scons

I'm trying to build an application using scons on x86-64 host Windows machine for Windows ARM64 target. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 cross-compilers for ARM64 ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx64\arm64")

My scons environment initialization is as follows:

```
tmpenv = Environment(options = opts, ENV= {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']}, TARGET_ARCH = 'ARM64', HOST_OS = 'x86_64', MSVC_VERSION = '14.2', MSVC_SDK_VERSION='10.0.18362.0', TARGET_OS='ARM64', MSVS_ARCH = 'arm64')
```

and manually setting the compilers and linkers:

```
env["CXX"] = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\Hostx64\\arm64\\cl.exe\""
env["CC"] = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\Hostx64\\arm64\\cl.exe\""
env["LINK"] = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\Hostx64\\arm64\\link.exe\""
env["LD"] = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\Hostx64\\arm64\\lib.exe\""
env["AR"] = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\Hostx64\\arm64\\lib.exe\""
```

But with these settings, when cpp files are compiled, object files with ".o" suffix and libs with "lib" prefix & ".a" suffix are being generated which are Linux related. It throws the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'libtest.a'
```

Can anyone help me where I'm going wrong?

Also, when I explicitly set the MS tools like:

```
tmpenv.Tool('msvc')
tmpenv.Tool('mslink')
tmpenv.Tool('mslib')
```

Compilation runs as expected but at the end it throws `'ranlib' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` error. Somehow ranlib is getting picked.

Comment: I don't think `lib.exe` can be used as a substitute for `LD` or `AR`.

Comment: @user7860670 even after removing those 2, its the same

Comment: It seems like `ranlib` is some Linux tool which is probably why it doesn't work with MSVC? I totally guessing but maybe SCons chooses by default some Linux toolchain and sets some values that are not reset by the MSVC tools. Try to add argument `tools=[]` to creation of your environment and see if this helped.

Comment: This should work much more simply, by only setting `TARGET_ARCH`. The default on Windows is the msvc toolchain so you should not need to set anything else. If you're not using 4.4, suggest switching - there was a large improvement to the toolchain setup contributed for that version. You might want to join the scons DIscord chat for more interactive help (see scons.org to find a link) - SO is better suited to someone posting "an answer" which is hard to do in this case - we can add one here later to close the loop.

Comment: Which version of python? Which version of SCons? How did you install SCons?

Comment: @bdbaddog Python version - 2.7 , scons version - 3.1.1. Installed scons by running setup.py file with install argument

Comment: @NO_NAME Thanks for the solution. Tried tools=[]. then set the required tools like msvc, mslib, mslink, etc. It worked!

Comment: @YESHU - that's a very old version of SCons. You may be able to do this much simpler with SCons 4.4.0 (which requires python 3.6+)